# How to remove camera icon from the browser address bar even after closing the video streams

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediastream, peer-connection, mediastreamtrack

I have tried using this code to remove icon of camera and microphone that appeared in browser even after closing the stream

[image]

```js
var videoTrack = this.localStream.getVideoTracks()[0]
    if(videoTrack){
      this.localStream.removeTrack(videoTrack)
      videoTrack.stop()
    }

    var audioTrack = this.localStream.getAudioTracks()[0]
    if(audioTrack){
      this.localStream.removeTrack(audioTrack)
      audioTrack.stop()
    }
```

Also, I tried. But no luck.

```js
this.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track => {
        track.stop();
      }))
```

How can i remove these icons from browser.

I am using webRTC

Comment: Are you sure you don't do an other request to the devices in other tracks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I release the camera and microphone after a WebRTC call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732910/how-do-i-release-the-camera-and-microphone-after-a-webrtc-call)